# Increase the opacity of the custom watermark in MSoffice

Tags: ms-word

I am using MS office 2010 and i want to include a water mark image, I found that under the page layout menu but it is very light i want to make it brighter how can i make it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your print the document (using watermark method) it will darken the watermark to normal colors then.  Its only when you are in edit mode that the watermark will appear faded.  Do a print preview of your watermark to see the results.

Answer (score 0):

How are you inserting the watermark? 
Try first getting a picture the way you want it and then add it as a header/footer to make it a watermark. That will give you more control.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I just wanted the opacity issue in the watermark i,e.. about brightness of the image